# WinPython 3.8.5 gave me Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.8

I have downloaded **WinPython 3.8.5** I can see the folder inside is **python-3.8.5.amd64** which is good but when I stroke `python --version` (in WinPython Scripts folder) it throws me 2.7 :(

Then when I pip install a module I have this warning :

> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.

In Program Files I have a folder : **Python.2715**

What's the problem here ? Help please, how can I have Python 3 with WinPython ?

Comment: Put the WinPython folder earlier to your PATH environment variable than other Python folders.

Comment: @pts Thanks for your help. However, I've opened CMD in the Scripts folder of WinPython, moreover, I have tried to put the folder earlier as you mentioned and I have still the same 2.7 warning...

Comment: To make sure, start Python explicitly as C:\...\python.exe , and pip likewise. (Maybe PATH is still incorrect, or you don't habe the pip command installed for Python 3.)

Comment: Thanks, it works for python, I can see 3.8 in console. However, how to use pip then ? In Scripts folder I open cmd and do pip install but pip says it is python 2.7...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put the WinPython folder containing *python.exe* earlier to your `PATH` environment variable than other Python folders. Verify the version by running `python -V`.
2. To install packages, use `python -m pip install ...` instead of `pip install ...`. (It looks like `pip install` tries to use the *pip* command from another version of Python on your `PATH`. Maybe the direct reason for this is that your WinPython folder doesn't contain the `pip` command or the relevant subfolder is not on your `PATH`. To fix `pip install`, you may want to reinstall WinPython, and then report a bug to the WinPython maintainers.)